# WooCommerce woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents hook with custom text

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add a custom text on the checkout form

I have used the following hook but the message actually ended up on top of the product and not after the cart contents And it appeared twice

```php
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'payable_now');
function payable_now() {
    echo 'Payable Now';
}
```

[Payable Now - no ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng5oS.jpg)

Then I tried the following hook which did not return the message twice but it still added the Payable Now on top of the Product

```php
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'payable_now');
function payable_now() {
    if ( ! is_ajax() ) {
        echo 'Payable Now';
    }
}
```

[Payable now with ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLtNs.jpg)

Where I actually nee the text to appear is right after the start date displaying here

[Where payable now should display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIms0.jpg)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
include the current result, include the expected result,
 provide more information about the problem: 
screenshots
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Answer (score 1):

use a table element as tr td th

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'payable_now');
    function payable_now() {
         echo '<th> Payable Now </th>';
    }
```